# In Zelda, Ocarina of time; what do I do next after the Fire Temple?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

I just completed the Fire Temple.

I headed over to Zora's domain and see that everything is frozen over.  At this point, I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the blue fire, which you can use to unfreeze king Zora. Go past the frozen King to Jabu Jabu's area - there will be ice platforms you can jump from to make it to the island you saw in the area when you were a kid.

Good luck in the Ice Cavern!

Comment: Don't forget the iron boots.